# Помогите пожалуйста найти и исправить ошибку в коде

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку. Ошибка - inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation (на строке 69). Сам код:

```
import time
import random
import easygui

def Stalker():
    
    # переменные
    history = "Однажды, на АЭС №7, произошла авария, которая унесла за собой много жизней. Животные мутировали, а на улице без противогаза находиться нельзя. 85% людей, умерли от лучевой болезни, 5% погибли от голода и жажды,"  
    items_all = ["АК 47", "Батарейки", "Аккумулятор", "Кольт", "Дигл", "Фамас", "Фн фал", "Канистра", "мак 10", "Патроны", "Бочка топлива", "П 90", "Доски", "Револьвер", "Турель", "Ауг", "Тек 9", "Винчестер", "Деньги"] # список предметов, которые могут случайно выпасти
    rand_items = ("АК 47", "Батарейки", "Аккумулятор", "Кольт", "Дигл", "Фамас", "Фн фал", "Канистра", "мак 10", "Патроны", "Бочка топлива", "П 90", "Доски", "Револьвер", "Турель", "Ауг", "Тек 9") # список оружий, которые могут случайно выпасти
    rand_guns = ("АК 47", "Кольт", "Дигл", "Фамас", "Фн фал", "мак 10", "П 90", "Револьвер", "Турель", "Ауг", "Тек 9")
    VVU = 0 # Доступность действия "Войти в убежище"
    oil = 0 # топливо
    money = 0 # Кол - во денег
    inventory = ["Винчестер", "Патроны"]
    bullets = 20
    hp = 30 # здоровье
    event_home = 0
    bochka = 0 # бочкии с бензином
    kan = 0 # канситры с бензином

    def random_item():
        rand_item = random.choice(rand_items)
        inventory.append(rand_item)

        if rand_item == "Патроны":  # если выпали патроны

            rand_bullets = random.randint(1, 20)
            bullets = bullets + rand_bullets

        elif rand_item == "Бочка":
            bochka = bochka + 1

        elif rand_item == "Канистра":
            kan = kan + 1
    
    easygui.buttonbox(      # информация
        
        title = "Сталкерские похождения",
        msg = f"история: {history}",
        choices = ("далее", " "))

    easygui.msgbox(      # старт
        
        title = "Сталкерские похождения",
        msg = "7% мутировали, а оставшиеся 3% живы, и среди них вы. А оварию подстроила компания OMEGA corp.")

    name = easygui.buttonbox(              # имя персонажа
        
        msg = 'Выберете имя персонажа: ', 
        title ='Сталкерские похождения',
        choices = ("Меченый", "Фантом"))

    easygui.msgbox(      # старт
        
        title = "Сталкерские похождения",
        msg = "Каждые 45 секунд, у вас будет повышаться здоровье на 1. Начнем игру!")

    while True:
        time.sleep(45)
        hp = hp + 1
    

    while True:

        if event_home == 7: # открытие убежища
            VVU = 1

        resh = easygui.buttonbox(      # Выбор действия
        
            title = "Сталкерские похождения",
            msg = "Выберете действие: ",
            choices = ("Сходить на разведку", "Войти в убежище", "Посмотреть инвентарь"))

        
        if resh == "Посмотреть инвентарь":
            easygui.msgbox(      
        
            title = "Сталкерские похождения",
            msg = f"Содержимое: {inventory}, патроны - {bullets}, монет - {money}")

        

        if resh == "Войти в убежище" and VVU == 0:
            easygui.msgbox(      
        
            title = "Сталкерские похождения",
            msg = "Это действие недоступно! Сходите 7 раз на разведку чтобы найти убежище.")

        
        if resh == "Войти в убежище" and VVU == 1: # убежище
            
            while True: 
                
                home = easygui.buttonbox(      
        
                title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                msg = "Вы в убежище, выберите действие: ",
                choices = "Назад", "Завести машину")

                if home == "Назад":
                    break

                if home == "Завести машину":
                    
                    location_LVL = easygui.buttonbox(       # выбор локации по уровню опасности
        
                    title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                    msg = "На какой тип локации по опасности хотите отправиться? Ур опасности - ",
                    choices = "1", "2", "3", "4", "5")

                    


                    if location_LVL == "1": 

                        location = easygui.buttonbox(       # легкие локации
        
                        title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                        msg = "На какую локацию хотите отправиться?",
                        choices = "Магазин", "Площадка", "Пятерочка")

                    if location_LVL == "2": 

                        location = easygui.buttonbox(       # средние локации
        
                        title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                        msg = "На какую локацию хотите отправиться?",
                        choices = "DNS", "М видео", "МЕГА")

                    if location_LVL == "3": 

                        location = easygui.buttonbox(       # сложные локации
        
                        title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                        msg = "На какую локацию хотите отправиться?",
                        choices = "Бандитская группировка Дельта", "Бандитская группировка Альфа", "Минное поле")

                    if location_LVL == "4": 

                        location = easygui.buttonbox(       # ОЧЕНЬ СЛОЖНЫЕ локации
        
                        title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                        msg = "На какую локацию хотите отправиться?",
                        choices = "Поле аномалий", "Лаборатория Х7", "Зона 51")

                    if location_LVL == "5": 

                        location = easygui.buttonbox(       # ULTIMATE DESTRUCTION!!! *полное уничтожение
        
                        title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                        msg = "На какую локацию хотите отправиться?",
                        choices = "Оружейный склад", "Банк", "OMEGA corp.")

                


                if home == "Завести машину" and oil == 0:
                    oil_2 = easygui.buttonbox(       # заправить машину
        
                    title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                    msg = "У вас слишком мало топлива! Хотите заправить машину?",
                    choices = "Да", "Нет")

                    if oil_2 == "Нет":
                        break
                    
                    if oil_2 == "Да":
                        
                        oil_3 = easygui.buttonbox(       # чем заправить машину
        
                        title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                        msg = "Чем вы хотите заправить машину?",
                        choices = "Бочка (100%)", "Канистра (50%)")

                        if oil_3 == "Бочка (100%)" and bochka == 0: # если бочек нет
                            
                            easygui.msgbox(      
        
                            title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                            msg = "У вас нет бочек!")
                            break

                        if oil_3 == "Бочка (100%)" and bochka <= 1:
                            oil = oil + 100 # топливо
                            bochka = bochka - 1
                            inventory.remove("Бочка")

                            easygui.msgbox(      
        
                            title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                            msg = "Вы заполнили бак на 100 едениц")

                        if oil_3 == "Канистра (50%)" and kan == 0:

                            easygui.msgbox( 
                            
                            title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                            msg = "У вас нет канистр!")
                            break

                        if oil_3 == "Канистра (50%)" and kan <= 1:
                            oil = oil + 50 # топливо
                            kan = kan - 1
                            inventory.remove("Канистра")

                            easygui.msgbox(      
        
                            title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                            msg = "Вы заполнили на 50 едениц.")

        if hp == 0:
            easygui.msgbox(      
        
            title = "Сталкерские похождения",
            msg = "У вас не осталось жизней! Игра окончена.")

            time.sleep(3)
            break

        if bullets == 0:
            inventory.remove("Патроны")

        

        if resh == "Сходить на разведку":

            event_home = event_home + 1 # убежище откроется если это значение бедет равно 7
            event_generate = random.randint(1, 5)

            
            if event_generate == 1:    # деньги
                kol_vo = random.randint(100, 500)
                
                money = money + kol_vo

                
                easygui.msgbox(      
        
                title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                msg = f"Вы нашли {kol_vo} монет(у, ы)")

            if event_generate == 2: # случайный предмет
                
                rand_item = random.choice(rand_items)
                inventory.append(rand_item)

                easygui.msgbox(      
        
                title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                msg = f"Вы нашли {rand_item}")

                if rand_item == "Патроны":  # если выпали патроны

                    rand_bullets = random.randint(1, 20)
                    bullets = bullets + rand_bullets

                    easygui.msgbox(      
        
                    title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                    msg = f"Вы нашли {rand_bullets}, патрон(а, ов)")

            

            if event_generate == 3: # мутант
                hp = hp - 4

                re = random_item()

                easygui.msgbox(      
        
                title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                msg = f"Вы встретили мутанта и убили его, он вам снес 4 жизни, у вас осталось {hp}. Вы получили с него {re}")
            

            if event_generate == 4: # сейф с лутом
                easygui.msgbox(      
        
                title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                msg = "Вы нашли сейф в котором что - то лежит, и пробуете его взломать.")

                attempets = 6 # попытки
                number = random.randint(1, 100) # код от сейфа
                reward = random.choice(rand_guns) # награда (случайное оружие)

                while True:
                    
                    if attempets == 0:
                        
                        easygui.msgbox(      
                        
                        title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                        msg = "У вас закончились попытки!")

                        time.sleep(3)
                        break

                    
                    number_user = easygui.integerbox(   # число пользователя   
                        
                    title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                    msg = "Нужно ввести код от сейфа, но каждый раз когда вы вводите код, показывается больше число или меньше. Всего у вас 6 попыток. Введите число от 1 до 100: ",
                    lowerbound = 1,
                    upperbound = 100)

                    if number_user > number:
                        attempets = attempets - 1

                        easygui.msgbox(      
                        
                        title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                        msg = "Ваше число больше!")

                    if number_user < number:
                        attempets = attempets - 1

                        easygui.msgbox(      
                        
                        title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                        msg = "Ваше число меньше!")

                    if number_user == number: # победа

                        easygui.msgbox(      
                        
                        title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                        msg = f"Вы угадали число! ваша награда - 1000 монет и {reward}")
                        money = money + 3000
                        inventory.append(reward)

                        time.sleep(3)
                        break

            if event_generate == 5:    # аномалия
                
                hp = hp - 10

                easygui.msgbox(      
                        
                title = "Сталкерские похождения",
                msg = f"Вы наткнулись на аномалию! Она ранила вас, у вас осталось {hp} здоровья.")




Stalker()
```

Comment: а ошибка то какая?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin вот - inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: проверьте везде отступы. Нельзя использовать табуляция и 4 пробела одновременно.

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin хорошо, проверю

Comment: С отступами как раз все нормально, у меня после копипаста с этим проблем не было.

Comment: @Assur а ошибка с пробелами и табуляцией просто так вылезла?

Comment: @Assur Спасибо! я только что попробовал скопипастить и все на удивление заработало!

Comment: @Assur На сайте все табы автоматически на пробелы заменяются...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка одного и того же типа повторяется в строках 99,110,121,129,137,145,153,163,174.
Выбор для choices это список. Из-за невнимательности вы перестали его обрамлять скобками(до этого в строках 41,52 и 73 все было правильно).

Код запустился и других ошибок пока не увидел.

Comment: опередили)
после Каждые 45 секунд, у вас будет повышаться здоровье на 1. Начнем игру! окно игры закрывается и дальше ничего не происходит

Comment: Ну так пусть человек дальше сам мучается с разработкой игры и сценария к ней))

Comment: думаю за сегодня на SO еще не 1 вопрос появится про эту игру)

Comment: @Assur спасибо большое!